# Can I check for cells with a color filling in a pandas Dataframe originated from an excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I want to know how to make a condition so as to iterate through every cell in each column of a Dataframe checking if the cell in the original excel had any color filling.

I tried using the Openpyxl library but I couldn't find a concise way of doing it. As the excel file is .xlsx I also can't use xlrd.

Comment: Use `openpyxl`. Pandas cares (mostly) about the data, not the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your *openpyxl*'s code but you can still use [`xlsx_cells`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [janitor](/questions/tagged/janitor) :

```
# pip install pyjanitor
from janitor import xlsx_cells

cells = xlsx_cells("file.xlsx", sheetnames="Sheet1", fill=True)

m = cells["fill"].str["fgColor"].str["tint"].ne(0)

cells.loc[m, "coordinate"].tolist() # ['C2', 'B3', 'B4']
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: **NB**: If needed, check [this](https://support.tmssoftware.com/t/bgcolor-vs-fgcolor/3357/2) post to understand the difference between *fgColor* and *bgColor*.